# Filling in NA for added vector to Dataframe

Tags: r

I have two (or more) vectors and would like to add them into a dataframe with the empty space being replaced by NA without having to specify in the declaration of the vector. Is this even possible?

```
df <- data.frame()
e <- c(1,2,3,4)
q <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
df <- rbind(df, e)
df <- rbind(df, q)
```

To get

```
   x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
1  1  2  3  4  NA
2  1  2  3  4  5
```

Instead of

```
   x1 x2 x3 x4
1  1  2  3  4
2  1  2  3  4
```

Comment: you can use bind_rows in dplyr , I also post my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Put all vectors in a list    
mylist = list(e, q)
#Find out the length of the vector with most elements
max_length = max(lengths(mylist))
#subset all vectors to extend to the max_length and rbind
data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(mylist, function(x) x[1:max_length])))
#  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
#1  1  2  3  4 NA
#2  1  2  3  4  5
```

The main *trick* is that if you subset a vector beyond the actual number of elements it has, the remaining elements will be `NA`. Test

```
(1:5)[1:7]
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the quick and accurate response.

Answer (score 0):

In `dplyr::bind_rows`

```
df <- data.frame()
e <- c(1,2,3,4)
q <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
df1 <- rbind(df, e)
df2 <- rbind(df, q)
bind_rows(df1,df2)

  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  1  2  3  4 NA
2  1  2  3  4  5
```